# GTM google-site-verification show me a text

Tags: html, css, api, google-tag-manager

I have a problem. When I add GTM (GoogleTagManager) to a site

I get a text `google-site-verification: googlexXxxxXxXXx.html` after the script.

that I can not remove, how do I do it?

Comment: Please add a snippet of the relevant HTML to your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u8f0fgm6/

Comment: Thanks for the test case - very strange. Are you using GTM to verify your site ownership, as described here? https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/06/verify-your-site-in-webmaster-tools.html Do you have the option to try verification via DNS records instead?

Comment: when trying to validate by GTM, it shows me an error, and validate the property per file. and remains the same. :(

Comment: That may be what you have to do first: follow the Google site verification-by-file instructions: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en#html_verification